# A puzzle about YET

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am reading North and South (Chap. 15) of Elizabeth Gaskell. Here is a paragraph in this book.

> 'I don't know—I suppose because, on the very face of it, I see two
>   classes dependent on each other in every possible way, **yet each
>   evidently regarding** the interests of the other as opposed to their
>   own; I never lived in a place before where there were two sets of
>   people always running each other down.'

The "yet" here is apparently a conjunction, which should link two complete sentences and the latter part should be " yet each evidently **regards** the interests of the other". I don't know whether it is a special use of "yet" in the age of Gaskell or I am wrong about the usage of "yet"?

Comment: It means "I see two classes dependent on each other but apparently regarding the interests of the other instead of their own." The use of *yet* there means *but* or *although* and I find said usage unexceptional and unexceptionable. You might be perceiving more ambiguity in *regarding* than I do, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robusto mentions in his comment, replace "yet" with "but" and the sentence ought to make sense.

> The two classes depend on each other, **but** apparently always oppose the interests of each other, and constantly insult each other.

It's a pretty straightforward sentence, although the language is somewhat archaic -- unsurprising since the novel was originally published in 1854.